# Unable to expose frontend React app and backend Fast API app through nginx, only one of them works

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose, fastapi

I have a docker-compose application, it has three services react frontend deployed on 3000 port, fast api backend deployed on 8000 port, and ngnix deployed on port 80. My docker-compose looks as follows:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    container_name: frontend-conatiner
    restart: always
    build: ./Frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

  backend:
    container_name: backend-container
    restart: always
    build: ./Backend
    env_file:
     - ./Backend/.env.local
    volumes:
     - ./Backend/:/backend
    ports:
     - "8000:8000"
    command: uvicorn api.main:app --reload --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx-container
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    depends_on:
      - app
```

My nginx configuration looks like as follows:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name my_app;

    # Proxy settings
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    }
    # Backend Proxy settings
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is I am able to access my frontend at `http:localhost` but I am not able to access my backend fast API i.e. when I do `http:localhost/api/docs` I get `not found`. When I try to test the backend without nginx i.e. at `http:localhost:8000/docs` it works perfectly fine.

I have also tried switching the location of frontend and backend if I change my nginx configuration as follows then I am able to access backend but can not access frontend react app:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name my_app;

    # Proxy settings
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    }
    # Backend Proxy settings
    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://app:3000;
    }
}
```

So I am sure I am doing something wrong in nginx configuration, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is when you hit `http:localhost/api/docs`, it will redirect to `http:localhost:8000/api/docs`. And there is no such url, only we have `http:localhost:8000/docs`. And it will say `404 Notfound`

To resolve this, when the url have `/api`, then we have to redirect it to the backend without `/api` url path.

Update your `nginx` conf as

```
server {

        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        # Proxy settings
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://app:3000;
        }

        # Backend Proxy settings
        location /api/ {
            rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;
            proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
        }
    }
```

`rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /$1 break;` this will capture everything after `/api` and redirect to that path